# Real time plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, graphics, real-time

I'm very new to MATLAB and I was trying to display a real time plot of some calculations. I have an `N` sized vector and I work with `m` values at a time (say `m = N/4`), so I want to plot the first `m` values and then as soon as the second `m` values are calculated have them replace the first plot.

My approach was as follows:

```
for i=1:N,
  ...
  //compute m
  ...
  plot(m);
end;
```

but it fails to update the plot in every loop and waits for all the loops to finish to plot the data. My question is: Should I use another function instead of `plot` or could I add some delay in each loop?

I think there must be a way I'm not aware of for updating the plot instead of re-plotting it every time.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102654/how-should-i-update-the-data-of-a-plot-in-matlab

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a call to `DRAWNOW` to force the plot to update. See the [reference page](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/drawnow.html). Note that `DRAWNOW` causes the graphics event queue to be flushed, which may cause callbacks etc. to be executed.

Comment: It has been some time now, but you might want to look at and use doublebuffering. I don't remember where to set that option - but it sure made a difference at that time :)

Comment: Double buffering is a property of the figure - "set( gcf, 'DoubleBuffer', 'on' )" or similar. Might help too, but you need a DRAWNOW to force the update.

Answer (score 33):

As [Edric mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3115944/52738), you'll definitely want to include a [`drawnow`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) command after the call to [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) to force an update of the graphics. However, there is a much more efficient and smoother method to animate plots that doesn't involve recreating the entire plot each time. You can simply initialize your plot, capture a [handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/understanding-handle-graphics-objects.html) to the plot object, then modify the properties of that object in your loop using the [`set`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html) command. Here's an example:

```
hLine = plot(nan);         % Initialize a plot line (which isn't displayed yet
                           %   because the values are NaN)
for i = 1:N                % Loop N times
  ...
  % Compute m here
  ...
  set(hLine, 'YData', m);  % Update the y data of the line
  drawnow                  % Force the graphics to update immediately
end
```

In addition, before your loop and after the call to `plot` you can set a number of [axes properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html), like the [axes limits](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.axis.axes-properties.html#property_d119e50844), etc., if you want the axes to stay fixed and not change their appearance with each new vector `m` that is plotted.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Both yours and Edric's solution worked very well. But if I do it your way it won't have to replot everytime.

Comment: @vvy I accepted the other one since it came first and helped me solve my problem, but I then realised this one was better. I guess the number of votes speaks for itself.

Comment: @kirbuchi Usually people follow(only look at) the accepted answer. The *vote count* are not that *eye-catchy* as the **green-check-mark** ;)

Comment: @gnovice, could y please have a look at [real-time-plots-in-matlab-standalone-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46696542/real-time-plots-in-matlab-standalone-application)