# Real time plots in matlab standalone application

Tags: matlab, animation, plot, graphics, real-time

The application is a `GUI` designed with GUIDE with lots of `subplots` that have an refresh interval approx `~1s` adding new data to the time series, for example:

[image: gui]

I have read through [making-graphs-responsive-with-data-linking](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/making-graphs-responsive-with-data-linking.html#bricasr-1), but the efficient `linkdata on` does not work in standalone applications when exporting with application compiler:

`Error using linkdata (line 24)
Plots cannot be linked in deployed applications because linked plots require the MATLAB workspace.`

,while `refreshdata` works but results in heavy load.

What is the efficient way to plot data in real-time, is it still like gnovice suggests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3118918/4933053) and does this work for standalone's (lacking the workspace) efficiently too?

I also noticed `animatedline` [doc](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/animatedline.html), but dunno

machine: debian 9 x64