# How to speed up a very slow animated plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, performance, animation, profiler, drawnow

I'm trying to create an animated plot but my code is very slow, perhaps the method I'm using is too naive. In the below example, I have 4 subplots each with 3 lines, which I update in a 'time' loop.

```
clc;clear;close all;
state = {'$x-Position$','$x-Velocity$','$y-Position$','$y-Velocity$'};
ylabels = {'$x$','$\dot{x}$','$y$','$\dot{y}$'};
options1 = {'interpreter','latex'};
options2 = {'interpreter','latex','fontsize',20};
maxT = 300;

for pp = 1:4
    hh1(pp)=subplot(2,2,pp);
    xlabel('$t$',options2{:});
    ylabel(ylabels{pp},options2{:});
    title(state{pp},options1{:})
    xlim([0 maxT])
    hold on
end
x = randn(4,300);
z = randn(4,300);
x_est = randn(4,300);
for k = 2:maxT
    for p = 1:4
        plot(hh1(p),k-1:k,x(p,k-1:k),'b','linewidth',2)
        plot(hh1(p),k-1:k,z(p,k-1:k),'m')
        plot(hh1(p),k-1:k,x_est(p,k-1:k),':k','linewidth',2)
    end
    drawnow;
end
```

As can be seen from the [profiler output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGvdA.jpg), the `drawnow` is killing the time. Is there any way I can be more efficient in creating this animation?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115833/real-time-plot-in-matlab/3118918#3118918

Answer (score 5):

Because you want an animation, there is no alternative to using `drawnow` to update the frame. However, it's not `drawnow` in particular which is slowing you down - the profiler can be misleading... `drawnow` simply updates all of the graphics changes since the last re-draw, which in your case is a dozen new plots!

You'll find that `hold` is pretty slowing. For instance if you're wiser about your holding, remove the existing `hold on` and only hold when actually plotting

```
% ... above code the same but without 'hold on'
for p = 1:4
    hold(hh1(p), 'on');
    % plots
    hold(hh1(p), 'off');
end
```

This saves ~10% time on my PC (12.3sec down to 11.3sec).

---

The real speed up comes from removing `hold` entirely, along with all of the individual `plot` calls! This method also doesn't touch the line formatting which will help with speed. See a previous question about updating plot data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102654/how-should-i-update-the-data-of-a-plot-in-matlab).

**Simply update the plot data instead of adding plots**. This gives me a speedup of ~68% (12.3sec down to 4.0sec).

```
% ... your same setup
% Initialise plot data
x = randn(4,300);
z = randn(4,300);
x_est = randn(4,300);
plts = cell(4,3);
hh1 = cell(4,1);

% Loop over subplots and initialise plot lines
for p = 1:4
    hh1{p}=subplot(2,2,p);
    xlabel('$t$',options2{:});
    ylabel(ylabels{p},options2{:});
    title(state{p},options1{:})
    xlim([0 maxT])
    % Hold on to make 3 plots. Create initial points and set line styles.
    % Store the plots in a cell array for later reference.
    hold on
    plts{p,1} = plot(hh1{p},1:2,x(p,1:2),'b','linewidth',2);
    plts{p,2} = plot(hh1{p},1:2,z(p,1:2),'m');
    plts{p,3} = plot(hh1{p},1:2,x_est(p,1:2),':k','linewidth',2);
    hold off
end
% March through time. No replotting required, just update XData and YData
for k = 2:maxT
    for p = 1:4
        set(plts{p,1}, 'XData', 1:k, 'YData', x(p,1:k) );
        set(plts{p,2}, 'XData', 1:k, 'YData', z(p,1:k) );
        set(plts{p,3}, 'XData', 1:k, 'YData', x_est(p,1:k) );
    end
    drawnow;
end
```

Now the plotting is pretty optimised. If you want the animation to be *even quicker* then just plot every 2nd, 3rd, ..., nth timestep instead of every timestep by using `for k = 2:n:maxT`.

Comment: @user5045 No worries, feel free to mark this answer as accepted using the green check mark if it helped!